# Filtering a single-column NSTableView using NSArrayController

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I present a sheet with an `NSTableView` (one column), an `NSSearchField` and an `NSButton` ('Add').
What I want is to set the content of the table view to a list of strings. This list of strings is in an `NSArray` called *list*. This content should be filtered based on the content of the search field (if a string in *list*) does not contain the content of the search field it is not shown in the table view anymore.

I'm not familiar with bindings, can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have uploaded a [project](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5393575/array-controller-search-59k?da=y), kindly check.

A rough idea how to do is as: (however understanding is easier by seeing the project)

1. Create an Array Controller.
2. Set for Array controller Object

   ```
     Mode:Class

     Class Name: Your custom Class
   ```
3. Received Actions

   ```
     add: to the button that will add new objects, typically labelled with +

     remove:to the button that will add new objects., typically labelled with -
   ```
4. Referencing Bindings(either from table or from here for each column of table).
5. For search field

   ```
    Bindings, Predicate to Array Controller

    ControllerKey : filterPredicate

    Predicate Format : <class property> contains $value

    (if to search in multiple table columns  then <class property 1> contains $value || <class property 2> contains $value etc…. )
   ```

Comment: Works great! Just a question : is it possible to do this without a custom class? It'd be silly to have to create a whole class that has only one `NSString` as instance variable. At the moment I use `-setContent:` on the Array Controller but I'm not sure how to bind its values to the table view and all the rest.

Comment: Nevermind! I found some old code of myself and I was binding the content of the table view instead of binding the value of the column. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Remember its name : Array Controller not string controller... I hope you got the answer :p

Comment: If you want just a string, simply `create a property of type string`. In the arrayController set the clasName that contains the string. For table change the binding to that string. Do same with the searchBar... thats it. It will work without creating a new class having only a single string.

Comment: Actually just using `self` instead of a class property works! Thanks for the very clear answer!!!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Hi, do basically a NSArrayController only works with an Array of dictionaries ?

Comment: @Jai: NO it can work with any collection. But mainly we use with Array and Dictionary.

Comment: In my case typing plain <class property> did not work, but self.<class property> did.