# Binding one NSSearchField's text to two different controller objects

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nssearchfield

I have two different NSArrayControllers but I'd like to use the text of one search field to filter them both.  The predicate would be different for each controller.  Is it possible?  Right now I can only get it to filter one array controller at a time.

Comment: you want to do it while you are typing the characters or on enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES this is possible.**

You can do it as : [This Stack Overflow answer by me shows how to do for one table and ArrayController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121152/filtering-a-single-column-nstableview-using-nsarraycontroller/14121637#14121637).

For multiple you just need to add a new predicate, which will say as `Predicate2`. Please refer the screen shot:

*Here Teacher and Student class contains a property `name`. However yo can have different property name. Also I am filtering only on one column or property you can search it for multiple columns/properties, for this refer the above link.*

[image]

Comment: Weird, I tried this but could not get it to work - nothing happened. I ended up using the NSTextDelegate to catch changes on the search field and manually setting the filterPredicate on the array controller from that. I'll mark your answer correct though, as I'll assume I just did something wrong.

Comment: Mostly Tuesday I will upload this same running code to figure you out for any silly mistake. As currenly on holidays and not having Mac with me.